# Calculator Javascript/Jquery storing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, calculator

I am a new student understanding javascript.  I am currently having a difficult time understanding a simple concept on storing a variable on my calculator side project.  My problem is when a operator (+,-,/,*) is clicked, I want to store the first value as a variable (first user input).  Then after the user clicks on the digits again, the display screen will clear and display the second variable (or the second user input).  Then if the operator button or equals button is pressed it will calculate the two variables (so var + var2). I have used a global variable for variable1, but I am having trouble assigning the second variable with the user input after clearing the item.  I have a feeling there is a simple answer to this question, but I want to know what I am fundamentally doing wrong so I can start reviewing all the topics I need to do cover again. Anyways any help will be great! Thanks

```
'http://codepen.io/kevk87/pen/EVoEaa`
```

Comment: just curious; teachers are starting students off with jquery to help them understand javascript? I would have thought they would have taught plain javascript before moving to jquery.

Comment: I am currently in a bootcamp which is more focused on UI/UX.  So in terms of teaching us front end development, it is more of an add on to the program compared to other bootcamps.  So the structure of the program is a little difficult to keep pace if you are completely new to javascript.  First we had to learn javascript/jquery in the virtual phase using treehouse or lynda (online learning on our own).  Then during the first week of class we were told to build a carousel.  So to answer your question, I believe we were expected to know javascript before the in-class session.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. Thanks for the explanation. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you have a syntax error in your statement that is causing jQuery to not select the right element.  I have fixed that in my snippet below.

Second, you need to implement the equal operator to put all of this together.  Meanwhile, to address your problem and point you in the right direction, You aren't really capturing the second element.  Everytime the user clicks on an operator, you are reassigning the value that is on the screen to 'number' variable, then clearing the screen and assigning the value that is on the screen(which is clear because you just cleared it) to 'number2'.

One way to get around this is to check and see if the 'number' variable has a value, if so then you assign the next value to the 'number2' variable.  Here's a snippet of code that does this.

```
$(".operator").on("click",function() {
    if (number == null) {
        number = $("#screen").html();
    }
    else {
        number2 = $("#screen").html();
        $("#screen").html("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sohrab for the feedback!  I think I am getting confused on implementing the different states of when to assign the variable.  So if I am understanding this correctly,  once the user clicks on the operator button, I am checking to see if the first variable is not assigned.  If not, assign the first variable.  Afterwards, once the user clicks on another digit, assign the second variable then clear the screen?  I think I have been overthinking this process which has been difficult for me to get my head around...Anyways thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `#` selector on the line `$("screen").html("");`, jQuery won't select the correct element. Also you haven't implemented the equal operator yet.

```
$(".operator").on("click",function() {
    number = $("#screen").html();
    $("screen").html("");
    number2 = $("#screen").html();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Lam! I think I am getting confused with the calculator I am working with.  I was trying to have it so if the user keeps pressing the operator button after they enter the two digits, it will act as an equals button (like chaining the equation).  But I think I am overthinking it at the moment.  I should just get the basic equation by adding the two variables first.